# How to call Controllers method by name in new (ember-1.0.0-pre.4) version

Tags: ember.js

I used Ember.ready function to add some keyboard binding like this https://github.com/greggyNapalm/firebat-overlord/blob/master/web_static/static/js/app/app.js#L24 is there any proper way to do this in new version, asking because can't anymore call method by its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to do this sort of thing is from the view. Based on your example the appropriate view in this case is probably TestsView. From there you can bind and unbind keyboard bindings when the view is inserted/removed. For example:

```
var TestsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName:  'testsTemplate',
    didInsertElement: function() {
       console.log("Controller: " + this.get('controller').toString());
       var self = this;
       Mousetrap.bind('ctrl+right', function() {

         self.get('controller').goToPage('next');
       });
    },
    wilLRemoveElement: function() {
       Mousetrap.unbind('ctrl+right');
    }
});
```

To see what controller is set to, try adding `console.log("Controller: " + self.get('controller').toString());`

Comment: Thank You, this works well instead one thing: https://github.com/greggyNapalm/firebat-overlord/blob/ember-1.0.0-pre.4/web_static/static/js/app/app.js#L52 I got en erro: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined".
I tried to add controller like in docs: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/ but result was the same. What I'm doing wrong? What is the best place for controllers method call which fetch some data from server side?

Comment: Re: What I'm doing wrong? Sorry my bad, translated from coffeescript wrong. Updating my answer. Re: Best place for controllers/etc. hard to help with that via comments maybe post as a separate question.